# Kingfisher iOS image not loading

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, swift4, kingfisher

I am trying to dynamically set a UIImageView using [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher). The context is there is a TableView on the previous screen of different selectable rows and then when the row is selected a details UIView shows which has more information, including an image. I have gone to the Kingfisher documentation and found that the declaration belongs in the `viewDidLoad` as i have it but i still cannot get the image to load. I have also verified with debugging that the URL being passed to the Kingfisher is a link to a picture. I am thinking this may have to do with the image being set on a background thread but i am unsure how to fix that if that is the case. I have tried moving the implementation of the *Kingfisher* to the `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` functions and they still do not display the image even after an extended amount of wait time

Here is my code with some unrelated functionality removed.

```
import UIKit
import Kingfisher

class DetailsViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var thumbnail: UIImageView!

var thumbnailURL: URL?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.thumbnail.kf.setImage(with: thumbnailURL)

  ...................................................


//        self.thumbnail.image = UIImage(named: "image1")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the image url?

Comment: http:// books.google.com/books/content?id=OY48PgAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api

Here is an example image URL. I am trying to develop an app which uses the GoogleBooksApi

Comment: no http or https?

Comment: It is http. The hyperlink created removed that. I just added the space to not create a hyperlink, my bad

Answer (score 1):

kd02 - I have found the answer to my question. When you asked if it was http or https i remembered that you have to enable http in xcode 9 now because of the security enhancement. I did that and now it works.

Comment: Ah right, yeah that makes sense then. Happy coding :)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback though. I need to add a check for a nil URL so i needed that too

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
import UIKit
import Kingfisher

class DetailsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var thumbnail: UIImageView!

    var thumbnailURL: URL?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let url = self.thumbnailURL {

            self.thumbnail.setImage(with: url)
        }
    }
}
```

I have feeling the optional URL is causing the problem.